# Getting data from HTML using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to get data from HTML using DOM. I can get some data, but can't figure out how to get the rest. Here is an image highlighting the data I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WmwS.png

here is the code itself

http://pastebin.com/Re8qEivv

and here my PHP code

```
$html = file_get_contents('result.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($tr as $row){

    $td = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $td1 = $td->item(1);
    $td2 = $td->item(2);

    foreach ($td1->childNodes as $node){
        $title = $node->textContent;      
    }

    foreach ($td2->childNodes as $node){
        $type = $node->textContent;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out

```
$html = file_get_contents('result.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($tr as $row){

    $td = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $td1 = $td->item(1);
    $td2 = $td->item(2);

    $title = $td1->childNodes->item(0)->textContent;
    $firstURL = $td1->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');

    $type = $td2->childNodes->item(0)->textContent;
    $imageURL = $td2->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used following class.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

This is very simple and easy to use class.

You can use

```
$html->find('#RosterReport > tbody', 0);
```

to find specific table

```
$html->find('tr')
$html->find('td')
```

to find table rows or columns

Note $html is variable have full html dom content.

Comment: I tried it, but it struggles to load a single row from the table. It couldn't load a single row. This would hang my browser  http://pastebin.com/1XGv4r3h